# React JS app not opening in browser due to caching whenever a new edit is pushed to the server

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, caching, browser

I am using React JS. Whenever a new edit is pushed to the server, accessing the application becomes problematic. The app appears blank in browser. I have tried some ways of deleting cache but the issue is still happening

I have tried the following ways.

I have edited the head tag in index.html in this way

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

I have also added the following JS code on website load using useEffect hook.

```
const clearCacheData = () => 
{
   let version = localStorage.getItem('version');
   if(version != packageJson.version)
      {
        if('caches' in window){
          caches.keys().then((names) => {
            names.forEach((name) => {
              caches.delete(name);
          },
          console.log("cache is cleared"));
          });
          window.location.reload(true);
      };
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage.setItem('version',packageJson.version);
      }
  }
    

React.useEffect(() => {
    clearCacheData();
},[])
```

Comment: You need to change etag in your server header.

Comment: I don't any example of adding cache header directly in html. You need to add header in nginx, nodejs.